# Postgres function insert into values/parameter range

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I got an Postgres function with sth. like that:

```
INSERT INTO people.person (name, middlename, stat,city,tel [.....] )
VALUES ($2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7, [.....] ,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31)
```

Is there a way, I can use sth. like `VALUES ($2-$31)`? Couldn't find anything here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html.

Comment: Do you call that statement from another programming language or inside pgSQL? In the first case, you can create the string with something like `'..VALUES ($' + join([2..31], ',$') + ')'`...

Comment: The function gets called from another programming language. Thanks a lot man, your solution is what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome. Then please edit your question (add which programming language it is) and answer yourself -- maybe some other people have the same question and are happy to read a correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution from contradictioned, which works fine for me:

```
'..VALUES ($' + join([2..31], ',$') + ')'
```